# Access SQL: Choosing which table to SELECT from based on a condition

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

Consider the following situation:

I have a large set of queries that select from other queries that select from other queries, that have the task of adding up present, late, and absent from attendance tables, calculating percentages, etc. Now the client wants to be able to put in many different conditions to the query: to see only attendance on certain days of the week, to see attendance only in a certain date range, etc.

To perform all the calculations needed for each of the conditions would be time-consuming, so I would like the calculations to be performed only when the client requests that that calculation should be done. But I don't want to have to recreate my entire set of queries/reports for each type of condition that can be used. So I would like to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
IIf([a checkbox on a form that indicates whether the user wants the condition], 
    SELECT * FROM Attendance, 
    SELECT * FROM Attendance WHERE condition)
```

Because I don't want the calculations to be done if the user doesn't want them, this isn't a solution:

```
SELECT * FROM Attendance 
WHERE condition 
    OR NOT [a checkbox on a form that indicates whether the user wants the condition]
```

Is there some way to do this in Access SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to express the logic is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Attendance 
WHERE ([a checkbox on a form that indicates whether the user wants the condition] and condition) or
      (not [a checkbox on a form that indicates whether the user wants the condition] )
```

This formulation might allow MS Access to not evaluate the condition.

If you want two different queries to run, depending on what the user chooses, then construct two different queries in the application and choose the appropriate one.

Comment: That did solve my problem, so I marked it as the answer. However, though I can't think of a practical situation for it now that you solved my problem, I'm curious to know the answer to my original question: How do I "choose the appropriate one" using SQL?

Comment: @clum . . . You either create two queries in the application or you generate the appropriate `where` clause and let the SQL engine optimize it for you.